# Thread-Safe collection with no order and no duplicates

Tags: c#, .net, collections, concurrency, thread-safety

I need a thread-safe collection to hold items without duplicates. `ConcurrentBag<T>` allows non-unique items and `HashSet<T>` is not thread-safe. Is there a collection like this in .NET Framework 4.5?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suggest you use a `ConcurrentDictionary` and just use a dummy value for each entry. It's annoying in terms of efficiency (having all those dummy values) but I suspect in the majority of applications that would be insignificant.

You may well want to wrap this in your own `ConcurrentSet` implementation, which just does enough for your purposes, so that you don't need to see the abstraction leakiness in much of your code.

Comment: Does the type of the "dummy value" make a difference? Would using `ConcurrentDictionary<MyType, object>` and setting values to null be sufficient?

Comment: @ŞafakGür: You could do that, or perhaps use an `int` with a value of 0. Using something smaller than `int` is probably pointless due to memory alignment.

Comment: @ŞafakGür the two most common things I see are either using null for all values, or (for reference types) always making both the key and value for each pair the same instance.

Comment: @Servy: Thanks, setting the same reference for both key and value makes sense but I wrapped ConcurrentDictionary as ConcurretSet like Jon advised and I may use it for both reference types and value types. I guess I'll go with null.

Comment: @ŞafakGür: The *key* type you use is independent of the *value* type you use. So for a `ConcurrentSet<T>` you can create a `ConcurrentDictionary<T, int>`.

Comment: @ŞafakGür If you are making your own `ConcurrentSet` I agree with jon, use `<T,int>` and just ignore the values entirely.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I don't get why using something smaller than int is pointless. Doesn't this mean with every new item I get an extra integer? Is it better than references to null (or any reference type)?

Comment: @ŞafakGür: Well a null reference will always be *at least* 4 bytes, and may well be 8. It's not like a null reference takes no space. But objects are generally aligned in memory on 4 or 8 byte boundaries - so even if you make it a `ConcurrentDictionary<T, byte>` it's likely to take the same memory.

Comment: @ŞafakGür: If `TKey` is a reference type, making `TValue` won't likely waste more space than one is stuck wasting anyway, and will offer the advantage that one may find the key object associated with a particular key, which may in some cases be a useful operation.  For example, if one will be doing many comparisons among a large number of long strings, many of which, though generated independently, will contain the same sequences of characters, it may be useful to store them in a `Dictionary<string,string>`, and for each string, `myString = MyDict[myString];`.  Even though...

Comment: ...replacing each string with the one in the dictionary wouldn't change it semantically, comparing two string variables that refer to the same long string is much faster than comparing two string variables that refer to identical but distinct long strings.  I wonder why `Dictionary` doesn't otherwise allow one a means of getting the stored key associated with a key value?

Answer (score 20):

Here's some code I just wrote that does this ConcurrentSet construct:

```
public class ConcurrentSet<T> : IEnumerable<T>, ISet<T>, ICollection<T>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<T, byte> _dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<T, byte>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through the collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1"/> that can be used to iterate through the collection.
    /// </returns>
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _dictionary.Keys.GetEnumerator();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through a collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An <see cref="T:System.Collections.IEnumerator"/> object that can be used to iterate through the collection.
    /// </returns>
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if <paramref name="item"/> was successfully removed from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>; otherwise, false. This method also returns false if <paramref name="item"/> is not found in the original <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="item">The object to remove from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.</param><exception cref="T:System.NotSupportedException">The <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> is read-only.</exception>
    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return TryRemove(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of elements in the set.
    /// </summary>
    public int Count
    {
        get { return _dictionary.Count; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> is read-only.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> is read-only; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value that indicates if the set is empty.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get { return _dictionary.IsEmpty; }
    }

    public ICollection<T> Values
    {
        get { return _dictionary.Keys; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an item to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The object to add to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.</param><exception cref="T:System.NotSupportedException">The <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> is read-only.</exception>
    void ICollection<T>.Add(T item)
    {
        if(!Add(item))
            throw new ArgumentException("Item already exists in set.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Modifies the current set so that it contains all elements that are present in both the current set and in the specified collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">The collection to compare to the current set.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="other"/> is null.</exception>
    public void UnionWith(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        foreach (var item in other)
            TryAdd(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Modifies the current set so that it contains only elements that are also in a specified collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">The collection to compare to the current set.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="other"/> is null.</exception>
    public void IntersectWith(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        var enumerable = other as IList<T> ?? other.ToArray();
        foreach (var item in this)
        {
            if (!enumerable.Contains(item))
                TryRemove(item);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes all elements in the specified collection from the current set.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">The collection of items to remove from the set.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="other"/> is null.</exception>
    public void ExceptWith(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        foreach (var item in other)
            TryRemove(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Modifies the current set so that it contains only elements that are present either in the current set or in the specified collection, but not both. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">The collection to compare to the current set.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="other"/> is null.</exception>
    public void SymmetricExceptWith(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether a set is a subset of a specified collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the current set is a subset of <paramref name="other"/>; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="other">The collection to compare to the current set.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="other"/> is null.</exception>
    public bool IsSubsetOf(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        var enumerable = other as IList<T> ?? other.ToArray();
        return this.AsParallel().All(enumerable.Contains);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the current set is a superset of a specified collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the current set is a superset of <paramref name="other"/>; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="other">The collection to compare to the current set.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="other"/> is null.</exception>
    public bool IsSupersetOf(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        return other.AsParallel().All(Contains);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the current set is a correct superset of a specified collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ISet`1"/> object is a correct superset of <paramref name="other"/>; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="other">The collection to compare to the current set. </param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="other"/> is null.</exception>
    public bool IsProperSupersetOf(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        var enumerable = other as IList<T> ?? other.ToArray();
        return this.Count != enumerable.Count && IsSupersetOf(enumerable);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the current set is a property (strict) subset of a specified collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the current set is a correct subset of <paramref name="other"/>; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="other">The collection to compare to the current set.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="other"/> is null.</exception>
    public bool IsProperSubsetOf(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        var enumerable = other as IList<T> ?? other.ToArray();
        return Count != enumerable.Count && IsSubsetOf(enumerable);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the current set overlaps with the specified collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the current set and <paramref name="other"/> share at least one common element; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="other">The collection to compare to the current set.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="other"/> is null.</exception>
    public bool Overlaps(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        return other.AsParallel().Any(Contains);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the current set and the specified collection contain the same elements.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the current set is equal to <paramref name="other"/>; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="other">The collection to compare to the current set.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="other"/> is null.</exception>
    public bool SetEquals(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        var enumerable = other as IList<T> ?? other.ToArray();
        return Count == enumerable.Count && enumerable.AsParallel().All(Contains);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an element to the current set and returns a value to indicate if the element was successfully added. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the element is added to the set; false if the element is already in the set.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="item">The element to add to the set.</param>
    public bool Add(T item)
    {
        return TryAdd(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _dictionary.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _dictionary.ContainsKey(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copies the elements of the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> to an <see cref="T:System.Array"/>, starting at a particular <see cref="T:System.Array"/> index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="array">The one-dimensional <see cref="T:System.Array"/> that is the destination of the elements copied from <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>. The <see cref="T:System.Array"/> must have zero-based indexing.</param><param name="arrayIndex">The zero-based index in <paramref name="array"/> at which copying begins.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="array"/> is null.</exception><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="arrayIndex"/> is less than 0.</exception><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentException"><paramref name="array"/> is multidimensional.-or-The number of elements in the source <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> is greater than the available space from <paramref name="arrayIndex"/> to the end of the destination <paramref name="array"/>.-or-Type <paramref name="T"/> cannot be cast automatically to the type of the destination <paramref name="array"/>.</exception>
    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        Values.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public T[] ToArray()
    {
        return _dictionary.Keys.ToArray();
    }

    public bool TryAdd(T item)
    {
        return _dictionary.TryAdd(item, default(byte));
    }

    public bool TryRemove(T item)
    {
        byte donotcare;
        return _dictionary.TryRemove(item, out donotcare);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the actual code but I can't un-accept Jon's answer since all I asked was whether .net has an alternative or not and he gave pointers for me to do exactly this. Your implementation is better than mine, though. Thank you, I'm going to use this. I just wish I could give more upvotes.

Comment: That's okay. To be honest I didn't look at the date of your question since I was just searching for my own solution. I thought I was answering an age-old question, not something from a few days ago. :-)

Comment: I recently took another look at this and I think `SymmetricExceptWith` can be implemented like this: `foreach (var item in other) if (!Remove(item)) Add(item);` I have no idea when will I ever use that one though.