# Are Dictionary and SortedSet thread safe for READERS in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, enumerator

If I don't modify a collection is it safe for 2 threads to run

```
        foreach (var el in collection)
            Console.Write(el);
```

at the same time?
The docs are kinda ambiguous. They do say - "not thread safe", but don't clearly say if they are READER thread safe.

MSDN says :
"To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization."

What about just for reading?

I did a heavy pounding test hoping to catch threads trampling over each other but so far List, Dictionary and SortedSet all seem to not get confused by multiple readers enumerating over them. Not enough to declare them thread safe for reading, but some food for thought.

```
    SortedSet<int> m_List = new SortedSet<int>();        

    void Test()
    {
        // Put 10,000,000 integers into a collection
        for (int i = 1; i < 10000000; i++)
            m_List.Add(i);

        // Start 10 threads 
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            (new Thread(Act)).Start(i);
    }

    Random rand = new Random();

    private void Act(object id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("---- Started Thread: {0}", id);

        int i = 0;
        int r = rand.Next(10000);

        foreach (int j in m_List)
        {
            if (j != ++i) // the thread safety check:
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NOT THREAD SAFE!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            }

            if (j%10000 == r)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("{0} yeld at {1}", state, j);
                Thread.Yield(); // to encourage threads intermingling.
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("---- Finished Thread: {0}", id);
    }
```

Comment: There are thread safe collection. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Read what I wrote http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960534/is-contains-thread-safe-in-hashsett/28960891#28960891

Answer (score 0):

For `Dictionary<T,T>`, The document states clearly:

> A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently,
>   **as long as the collection is not modified**.

So if you never modify the dictionary during read, it is fine to have multiple readers reading from the dictionary at once.

`SortedSet<T>` instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe, as specified in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, the "Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently" Where did you see that statement specifically in the docs? What I found is "Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection can support multiple readers concurrently" immediately followed by the " Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe ..." etc. Which means to me that it's safe to say foreach(var key in dictionary.Keys) but is it then safe to look at dictionary[key] ?

Comment: It means the enumeration is not a thread-safe procedure *per se*. Thread-safe means the methods will *never* result in any undefined state or behaviour by multiple thread access, but for Dictionary you need to make sure by yourself no one is going to write to the dictionary during the enumeration. It is stated more clearly in `GetEnumerator()` method.

Comment: The GetEnumerator doc is the one I was originally referring to in the question. I would argue that it is LESS clear in that one. It does not address the READER thread safety at all. It talks about overall thread safety. And it is the same general statement as in SortedSet and other collections.